# Access MongoDB Atlas with private endpoint from ECS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, amazon-ecs, mongodb-atlas

I have a MongoDB Atlas DB which I get access to with private endpoint to my VPC in AWS.
I have tried to access it from an EC2 in my VPC and it works.
When I try to access it from a docker container running on ECS with Fargate it is unable to find the DB:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ...:1025: timed out,...:1026: timed out,...:1024: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: ..., topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('...', 1024) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('...:1024: timed out')>, <ServerDescription ('...', 1025) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('...:1025: timed out')>, <ServerDescription ('...', 1026) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('...:1026: timed out')>]>
```

The VPC service endpoint seems to be configured correctly since I am able to access the DB from EC2 instances in this VPC.

I though that since I use Fargate version 1.4 it may be related to attaching a public IP or not, I have tried to remove that but it didn't seem to help (I get the same error).

It is worth noting that before I had an EC2 server with mongo installed on it and accessing it with a specific IP worked.

I am not sure what extra data to provide so please feel free to ask for supplementary data or just suggest ways to debug this issue.

Comment: Can you verify if your subnet in which the fargate gets deployed is configured with the VPC endpoint.

Comment: I have tried to add all the subnets to the endpoint and still get the same error

Comment: I would verify that the EC2 instance and the ECS Fargate service have the same security group and are in the same subnet. If those are not the same then I would spin up a small EC2 instance with the same security group and subnet as the Fargate service, and test from there.

Comment: Although it seems an obvious answer it was a great one, thanks! I was able to solve it by verifying all the security groups are the same.